# How do I convert a string of utf-8 codes into the actual string

Tags: ruby, utf-8

I am writing a little tool that emulates a user on a webpage and want to process the information I get. The tool is written in Ruby(Version > 2.0).

Unfortunately I don't receive the string but an UTF-8 representation of the actual string. Something like this:

```
"\u0000\t\u0000\t\u0000N\u0000\t\u0000N\u0000\t\u0000\n"
```

How do I convert this string back into a "normal" string?

Thank you

Comment: something has gone wrong with what you are receiving, if that's really exactly it. That's not valid anything that can be converted to anything. If that was just 'something like' and not what you really have, give us what you really have and we can guess better what might be going on. It may be that you have a perfectly normal good utf-8 string already, but your terminal is just not able to display it. Or it could be something else. A utf-8 encoded string is a 'normal' string, as normal as it gets.

Comment: What you wrote was true. Thank you.